# Workflow doesn't create tasks anymore

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I created a custom workflow via copy&modify of the OOB feedback workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010. When the workflow is started there are usually tasks created for every participant of the workflow in a task list.

After installing the workflow to a new server I've got the problem that the workflow won't create the tasks anymore. It starts but the tasks are missing.

Here's what I found out or tried so far:

When I first publish the workflow from SharePoint Designer and then try to start it for the first time, I get an error. It isn't very specific and just says that the workflow encountered an error; return to page bla bla. But if I try again to start the workflow, it suddenly works. This always happens if I publish the workflow again. Unfortunately I couldn't find any clearer logs on that so far.

After the workflow is started, I can go to the status page. There it says that the workflow has been initiated with the following participants and lists them.

The SharePoint log tells me the following:

```
04/15/2013 16:56:25.77  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x3BC4  SharePoint Foundation   General 72n3    Medium  put file doc URL = Workflows/Zuarbeit Vorgang-1/Zuarbeit Vorgang-1.xoml.wfconfig.xml    f5d2a0f0-df72-40d8-9cf5-ebec970ce1fa
04/15/2013 16:56:56.98  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x342C  SharePoint Foundation   Database    tzkv    High    SqlCommand: 'DECLARE @@iRet int;BEGIN TRAN EXEC @@iRet = proc_WriteChunkToAllDocStreams @wssp0, @wssp1, @wssp2, @wssp3, @wssp4, @wssp5, @wssp6;IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done; DECLARE @@S uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @@W uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @@DocId uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @@DoclibRowId int; DECLARE @@Level tinyint; DECLARE @@DocUIVersion int;DECLARE @@IsCurrentVersion bit; DECLARE @DN nvarchar(256); DECLARE @LN nvarchar(128); DECLARE @FU nvarchar(260); SET @DN=@wssp7;SET @@iRet=0; ;SET @LN=@wssp8;SET @FU=@wssp9;SET @@S=@wssp10;SET @@W=@wssp11;SET @@DocUIVersion = 512;IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done; ;SET @@Level =@wssp12; EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateDocument @@S, @@W, @DN, @LN, @wssp13, @wssp14, @wssp15, @wssp16, @wssp17, @wssp18, @wssp19, @wssp20, @wssp21, @wssp22, @wssp23, @wssp24, @wssp25, @wssp26, @wssp27, @wssp28, @wssp29, @wssp30, @wssp31, @wssp32, @wssp33, @wssp34, @wssp35, @wssp36, @wssp37, @wssp38, @wssp39, @wssp40, @wssp41, @wssp42, @wssp43, @wssp44, @wssp45, @wssp46, @wssp47, @wssp48, @wssp49, @wssp50, @wssp51, @@DocId OUTPUT, @@Level OUTPUT , @@DoclibRowId OUTPUT,@wssp52 OUTPUT,@wssp53 OUTPUT,@wssp54 OUTPUT,@wssp55 OUTPUT ; IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done; EXEC @@iRet = proc_TransferStream @@S, @@DocId, @@Level, @wssp56, @wssp57, @wssp58; IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done;  EXEC proc_DirtyDependents @@S,1,@FU; EXEC @@iRet=proc_UpdateListItem @WebId=@wssp59,@SiteId=@wssp60,@ListID=@wssp61,@ItemId=@@DoclibRowId,@UIVersion=@wssp62, @NewUIVersion = @@DocUIVersion OUTPUT,@RowOrdinal=@wssp63,@ReturnRowset=@wssp64,@SystemUpdate=@wssp65,@ChangeLevel=@wssp66,@OnRestore=@wssp67,@Size=@wssp68,@ItemName=@wssp69,@IsDocLib=1,@MajorVersionsLimit=@wssp70,@MajorMinorVersionsLimit=@wssp71,@UserId=@wssp72,@Level=@@Level,@TimeNow=@wssp73, @tp_ContentTypeId = @wssp74,@tp_ModerationStatus=@wssp75,@nvarchar14=@wssp76,@nvarchar15=@wssp77,@nvarchar16=@wssp78,@tp_ItemOrder = @wssp79 , @eventData=@wssp80, @acl=@wssp81, @IsFirstRow=@wssp82; IF @@iRet <> 0 GOTO done;;IF @@iRet = 0 BEGIN  EXEC @@iRet = proc_EnsureTranLockNotRequired @wssp83, @wssp84, @wssp85; END; done: IF @@iRet = 0 BEGIN EXEC proc_UpdateDiskUsed @@S, 1; COMMIT; EXEC proc_GetLinkInfoSingleDoc @@S,@DN,@LN, @@Level; END ELSE ROLLBACK;  SET @wssp86=@@Level; SET @wssp87=@@iRet;'     CommandType: Text CommandTimeout: 0     Parameter: '@wssp0' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '82c7823d-4f3f-4eb8-aada-0c30836bf65e'     Parameter: '@wssp1' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '50519a53-a4f2-4b4f-b942-9a7bb8f2c9de'     Parameter: '@wssp2' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'     Parameter: '@wssp3' Type: VarBinary Size: -1 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp4' Type: VarBinary Size: -1 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp5' Type: VarBinary Size: 0 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp6' Type: VarBinary Size: 0 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp7' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'sites/Aktenhaltung/Workflows/Zuarbeit Vorgang-1'     Parameter: '@wssp8' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'Zuarbeit Vorgang-1.xoml'     Parameter: '@wssp9' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'sites/Aktenhaltung/Workflows/Zuarbeit Vorgang-1/Zuarbeit Vorgang...'     Parameter: '@wssp10' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '82c7823d-4f3f-4eb8-aada-0c30836bf65e'     Parameter: '@wssp11' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '4c65b99a-274e-4cc9-99ee-d6dda4baea2d'     Parameter: '@wssp12' Type: TinyInt Size: 1 Direction: Input Value: '1'     Parameter: '@wssp13' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'True'     Parameter: '@wssp14' Type: VarBinary Size: 8000 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp15' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '95172'     Parameter: '@wssp16' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '352'     Parameter: '@wssp17' Type: VarBinary Size: 0 Direction: Input     Parameter: '@wssp18' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '0'     Parameter: '@wssp19' Type: Bit Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'False'     Parameter: '@wssp20' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '19'     Parameter: '@wssp21' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '19'     Parameter: '@wssp22' Type: Int Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '320'   b9dad174-70c8-4f98-ab24-db94a7844eed
04/15/2013 16:56:57.61  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x3BC4  SharePoint Foundation   General 72n3    Medium  put file doc URL = Workflows/Zuarbeit Vorgang-1/Zuarbeit Vorgang-1.xoml.wfconfig.xml    ad5ef496-e965-4097-8351-e8bc4705a502
04/15/2013 16:57:22.08  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/Workflow.aspx?ID=7&List=%7B35A930D2-7412-4C16-AD02-394346B9866E%7D&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdev11%2Fsites%2FAktenhaltung%2FVorg%25c3%25a4nge%2FForms%2FVersions%2Easpx))  
04/15/2013 16:57:22.08  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/Workflow.aspx?ID=7&List=%7B35A930D2-7412-4C16-AD02-394346B9866E%7D&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdev11%2Fsites%2FAktenhaltung%2FVorg%25c3%25a4nge%2FForms%2FVersions%2Easpx)    66a11876-2f1c-44e8-ab52-bef6382723d6
04/15/2013 16:57:29.52  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/Workflow.aspx?ID=7&List=%7B35A930D2-7412-4C16-AD02-394346B9866E%7D&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdev11%2Fsites%2FAktenhaltung%2FVorg%25c3%25a4nge%2FForms%2FVersions%2Easpx)). Execution Time=7442,51126889032  66a11876-2f1c-44e8-ab52-bef6382723d6
04/15/2013 16:57:44.71  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (WorkflowTelemetryScope)   ea7f9aee-9ac0-4eb0-8850-99f768a8e12c
04/15/2013 16:57:45.37  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Workflow Infrastructure 72ew    Medium  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   ea7f9aee-9ac0-4eb0-8850-99f768a8e12c
04/15/2013 16:57:46.04  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime 961x    Medium  Not persisting state for request due to previous errors. Form Template: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:workflowInitAssoc:-AutoGen-2013-04-15T14:06:17:391Z   ea7f9aee-9ac0-4eb0-8850-99f768a8e12c
```

This especially makes me curious:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
but I've got no idea where it comes from.

Strange thing is... I can deploy the same workflow to another server and there it works, but I have no idea what the difference is.

Another log with options to "verbose"

```
04/15/2013 19:45:52.21  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/Postback.FormServer.aspx))  
04/15/2013 19:45:52.21  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/Postback.FormServer.aspx)    8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.22  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/Aktenhaltung    8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.24  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Web Controls    cm8z    Medium  Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Die Gruppe wurde nicht gefunden.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value). 8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.24  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Web Controls    cm8z    Medium  Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Die Gruppe wurde nicht gefunden.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value). 8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.25  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Web Controls    cm8z    Medium  Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Die Gruppe wurde nicht gefunden.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value). 8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.25  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Web Controls    cm8z    Medium  Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Die Gruppe wurde nicht gefunden.  Callstack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32 value). 8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.28  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Server   State Service   8kfs    Medium  The StateManager is disposing and calling ReleaseLockedStates() (Count=0)   8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.28  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x0DBC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/Postback.FormServer.aspx)). Execution Time=66.7643513351557  8a075b26-bfaf-4d93-b375-7dfe5211e108
04/15/2013 19:45:52.58  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List=%7B35a930d2-7412-4c16-ad02-394346b9866e%7D&ID=4&TemplateID=%7B29243487-4337-452b-82e9-f7ea60ca37dd%7D&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdev11%2Fsites%2FAktenhaltung%2FVorg%25c3%25a4nge%2FForms%2FVersions%2Easpx)) 
04/15/2013 19:45:52.58  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:http://dev11:80/sites/Aktenhaltung/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List=%7B35a930d2-7412-4c16-ad02-394346b9866e%7D&ID=4&TemplateID=%7B29243487-4337-452b-82e9-f7ea60ca37dd%7D&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdev11%2Fsites%2FAktenhaltung%2FVorg%25c3%25a4nge%2FForms%2FVersions%2Easpx)   91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.59  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/Aktenhaltung    91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.68  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.69  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.73  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=82,7971152758242  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.94  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.94  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.96  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData#2). Execution Time=30,9259975779045    91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:52.97  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (WorkflowTelemetryScope)   91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:53.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x1A08  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-application-server-admin-service)   6fd06312-6431-4fef-8355-e88ea72f3b3a
04/15/2013 19:45:53.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x1A08  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  dkd5    High    synchronizing search service instance   6fd06312-6431-4fef-8355-e88ea72f3b3a
04/15/2013 19:45:53.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x1A08  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  eff0    High    synchronizing search data access service instance   6fd06312-6431-4fef-8355-e88ea72f3b3a
04/15/2013 19:45:53.04  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x0A48  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-workflow)   0918879d-3570-4ff5-84ea-a2f30cdcec3d
04/15/2013 19:45:53.13  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:53.13  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:53.16  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData#1). Execution Time=54,0468132122937    91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:53.17  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x0A48  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-workflow). Execution Time=126.953565327437   0918879d-3570-4ff5-84ea-a2f30cdcec3d
04/15/2013 19:45:53.41  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Workflow Infrastructure 72ew    Medium  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:54.17  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:55.15  powershell.exe (0x3A38) 0x0E04  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    aae1    Medium  Updating server locks.  
04/15/2013 19:45:55.16  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpk    Medium  Unable to open Lookup list '{fd16426b-5d88-41f8-aad1-5b8c8fca83d2}'.[Error was 0x81020026]  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:55.65  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x25AC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-immediate-alerts)   bbd4cf07-9ee1-46e5-9e54-6f9e838762cb
04/15/2013 19:45:55.87  powershell.exe (0x3A38) 0x0E04  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    aae2    Medium  Successfully updated [0] server locks. pid=[14904]  
04/15/2013 19:45:57.85  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=3945,39752957429  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:57.86  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (DocumentSetEventReceiver.ItemUpdated). Execution Time=3980,18435303928 91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:57.86  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (Event Receiver (Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSetEventReceiver)). Execution Time=3980,61234039522  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:58.05  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x35C0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-workflow-failover)  0f085f1f-2d69-49ee-bcf7-ab3b9f52808b
04/15/2013 19:45:58.07  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x2C80  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job Health Statistics Updating) 047f51bb-31f6-4786-bc53-0e8bf1dd8a55
04/15/2013 19:45:58.07  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x2454  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Timer Job SchedulingUnpublish)    c34e0a9a-1c57-4b51-a30c-378c7fea2b10
04/15/2013 19:45:58.11  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x35C0  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-workflow-failover). Execution Time=60.9792585370487  0f085f1f-2d69-49ee-bcf7-ab3b9f52808b
04/15/2013 19:45:58.11  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x2C80  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject SearchServiceApplicationMonitoring Name=Monitoring_7F19A5D194F942e6A9856FCFD6EE6F63. Version: 499285 Ensure: False, HashCode: 49439919, Id: a241cdf4-f510-4ec5-828d-0c14435c8093, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Monitoring.TraceDiagnosticsProvider.UpdateServiceApplicationHealthStats()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)  047f51bb-31f6-4786-bc53-0e8bf1dd8a55
04/15/2013 19:45:58.12  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x2454  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job SchedulingUnpublish). Execution Time=48.0424187990373    c34e0a9a-1c57-4b51-a30c-378c7fea2b10
04/15/2013 19:45:58.22  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x2C80  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Health Statistics Updating). Execution Time=151.627092270107 047f51bb-31f6-4786-bc53-0e8bf1dd8a55
04/15/2013 19:45:58.22  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x25AC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-immediate-alerts). Execution Time=2570.01546285911   bbd4cf07-9ee1-46e5-9e54-6f9e838762cb
04/15/2013 19:45:58.37  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x1A08  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  dl2i    Medium  Search application 'Search Service Application': Provision start addresses in default content source.   6fd06312-6431-4fef-8355-e88ea72f3b3a
04/15/2013 19:45:58.46  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=6,79360086267947  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:58.49  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x20D0)   0x1A08  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-application-server-admin-service). Execution Time=5452.48572095057   6fd06312-6431-4fef-8355-e88ea72f3b3a
04/15/2013 19:45:58.50  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   E-Mail  8gsf    High    #160005: Ungültige Antwort von SMTP-Host "DEV11": 550 The address is not valid. .   91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:58.50  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    Der Vorgang kann nicht erfolgreich beendet werden.  Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>    91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:58.58  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=6,37818493691237  91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
04/15/2013 19:45:58.62  w3wp.exe (0x1BD4)   0x2F7C  InfoPath Forms Services Runtime 961x    Medium  Not persisting state for request due to previous errors. Form Template: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:workflowInitAssoc:-AutoGen-2013-04-15T14:06:17:391Z   91997706-1264-4847-98bf-e6ef94408a7f
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to turn on extended logs in Central Administration. It should help to find reason of error.

- In Central Admin: Monitoring -> Configure diagnostic logging
- In the
  Least critical event to report to the event log menu, select Verbose;
- In the Least critical event to report to the trace log menu, select
  Verbose;
- Click Ok;
- Restart SharePoint 2010 Tracing service;

Go to the Path specified for the Trace Log and reproduce the error.

[More info about configuring diagnostic logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I added another log - now with the verbose option - near the object reference error. There seem to be several other errors but I've got no idea if they have something to do with my workflow or where exactly they come from...